# Preventive Medical Care

Tags: cats, death

I would like to know about free or low cost medical care for my pet cats. I am on a low fixed income and I need to provide care for them. One of my cats was not feeling well and I could not afford to take him to the animal hospital. I woke up this morning and Mr. Hobbs was dead. This death could have  been prevented if I had access to medical care I could afford. I still have 3 cats in the home. Can you help me please. Mr. Hobbs death has got me utterly heartbroken. I want to be a responsible pet owner and provide them with all the proper care. I love my babies. I am so sad right now. Please help me find care for them all.

Answer (score 4):

I'm so sorry about the loss of Mr. Hobbs. The death of a beloved pet is always gut-wrenching. Please try to remember that he had a better life with the food, shelter and affection that you provided than he would have had on his own.

Shelters are very aware that the cost of medical care can mean the difference between keeping a pet in the home or being surrendered. Some shelters have made arrangements with vets to help with this problem. If you contact the shelters in your area and explain your situation, they may be able to refer you to such a programme.

Vets are also sensitive to the cost issue, and will often reduce prices for an owner with a low income, or arrange for payment over time. Again, the shelter may be able to refer you to a vet that they think would help you. Finally, when an animal is ill, you can always contact a vet, explain your situation, and ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know you're location, but there are usually free and low cost clinics available to those in need. The clinics usually don't have the resources to run every day, but weekends or a couple days a month people volunteer their time to help out. I know from personal experience that things can seem hopeless at times, but resources are out there it's just a matter of finding them.Without more specific info on your situation and location I can't give a more detailed answer. You can start with googling non-profit organizations,no-kill shelters, or contacting the humane society in your area for possible info on organizations willing to help.